# Chrome Half-Size Window Is Too Wide; Why and Can One Fix It?

Tags: google-chrome

In Windows (7 or 8, in my case), snapping a Chrome window to the left or right half of the screen (by using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or by dragging to the corresponding edges) results in the window taking up slightly more than half the screen.  On the screen I'm using now (900px wide), it results in about 60 extra pixels (almost 7%).  I've long found this supremely annoying because it often prevents properly using two windows snapped side by side, which is what the snapping feature is designed for.  I'm wondering if it's known why this happens, and if there's some way to correct it (perhaps a flag or extension?).

***Update:*** It appears this only happens with a window having many tabs.  The higher the tab count gets after first creating the problem, the worse the problem becomes (until it reaches a maximum).  See the below screenshots.  One might conclude the solution is to avoid having many tabs, but that is a lame solution.  Is there no way to prevent this behavior for those that find it undesirable?

**Normal behavior:**
[image]

**A wide window (right) is eclipsed by an active, normal half-width window:**
[image]

**The wide window, when active, eclipses the normal half-width window:**
[image]

**With a fewer, but still many tabs, the problem is less pronounced:**
[image]

Comment: Have you had anybody try this on another computer to see the results? I've just tested and this problem doesn't exist in either Win 10 or Win 7. Are you sure you aren't running with a non-standard DPI setting or something?

Comment: @Appleoddity - Well, this is intriguing but disconcerting. I just asked a colleague, and his machine behaves like yours.  However, I know for a fact that I've had the problem on several separate machines/installations.   It has never behaved normally for me.  The machine I'm on now uses the standard 96 dpi ("smaller"/100%) setting, but I have had some machines set to the "medium"/125% setting.  I had always assumed it was a "Google knows best" type of problem.  Now I'm baffled.

Comment: A screenshot may help us to better understand what you are seeing.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I've added an update and screenshots.  The issue appears related to windows that have a lot of tabs.  I've never noticed this because, well, I always have many tabs open. :\

Comment: I’ve tested again on Win 10 with approximately 40 tabs open and it still doesn’t do this. I can try again on Win 7 later. Try running in incognito mode without all your extensions.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I can confirm that it happens in Incognito, too.